# Visual Studio annoying autocomplete IF space -> #IF

Tags: visual-studio, autocomplete, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with VB.
When I type "if" and hit space it converts my "if" statement to "#If"

Every time I need to go back and delete # sign.
I checked other related posts, deep dived into Tools-Options-Text Editor section but could not find anything.
Besides it takes too much time in coding. I worked with Vs for many years that never happened. Sometime, with some update this problem faced, I dont know when.

best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Offf, It seems that comleteword feature dynamically changing the "suggestion" according to your last use. I write "if", it offered "#if" then without hitting space or enter I selected "if" with mouse from suggestion list...

and next time I wrote "if" and hit space it leaves it as it is.

Comment: So glad to hear that your issue is solved and please mark it as an the answer, that will help others to easier search this helpful information, it is just a reminder and thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I'll mark this as answer but I suspect there's much more deeper bug there. I'm using international keyboard and looks like VS2017 (with latest updates) intellisense works with capital letters but it cannot differentiate lower case international letters. For me starting to type "I" works fine. but "i" brings "#If" suggestions. as I said above if you select "IF" with mouse then intellisence engine works fine but only until VS IDE close. When you restart IDE problem shows itself again.

Anyways, maybe this experience helps others because its not just annoying also considering the amount of "If" statements we write causes many many hours of wasted time, not mentioning the distraction.